# Read the value and Share it via different apps in android

Tags: java, android, android-sharing

i have a problem with sharing data through Sharing Intent. Here's is code of sharing the data via different app.

```
  btnshare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String shareBody = "The Langitude: "+longi+"The Latitude:"+lati;
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,value);
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));


        }
    });
```

it just a button which is work for sharing . but now the prolem is i want share some value in that case (lati, longi which i've got from textview. how  can i pass the value to the message body of the share action.

for information here's the origin of '[lati' and 'longi']value they belong from different method but they are in same class.

```
private void getLocation() {

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.d("Location:", location.toString());
            double lati =location.getLatitude();
            double longii=location.getLongitude();
            double alt=location.getAltitude();

            txt_lati.setText("" +lati);
            txt_longi.setText(""+longii);
            return;

        }
```

here's the method where lati and longi belongs. now my question is how can i share the latitude(lati) and longitude(longi) values via sharing prompt? i mean how can i share that specific two data? fyi if i'm going to share this way the value isn't comming .something like v7.appcompact that kind of text filled up in message body.

Comment: Make lati & longii global variable (Class Level) instead of local variable

Answer (score 0):

you need to make your first app activity intent as action intent

like

```
<activity
    android:name=".FeedbackActivity" >  
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        <action android:name="com.example.foo.bar.YOUR_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and you can call it from another application

```
String CUSTOM_ACTION = "com.example.foo.bar.YOUR_ACTION";   
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(CUSTOM_ACTION);    
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: i don't get it, 

<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
the menifest file cosist of only one activity.

Comment: `String we= txt_lati.getText().toString();
                String la= txt_lati.getText().toString();
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String shareBody = "Data about current loacation";
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Simple Info");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The langitude:"+we + "The Latitude"+la );`




i've solved it via this way. thank you.

Comment: you need to handel using this getIntent().getString(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT);